# MySql custom select with join table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select SUM value after join another table with a condition. but not getting the joined table inside the custom SELECT column.

there is code

```
SELECT parti_a.`country`,

(SELECT SUM(`total_pts`) as country_pts FROM `team_members`
INNER JOIN `participants` as parti_b ON parti_b.ParticipantID=`team_members`.`participant` AND parti_b.country = parti_a.`country` ) as country_pts

FROM `team_members`
INNER JOIN `participants` as parti_a ON parti_a.`ParticipantID` = `team_members`.`participant`

WHERE `round` = 'B759883'
GROUP BY parti_a.`country`

ORDER BY team_members.total_pg + 1 DESC, team_members.total_pts + 1 DESC
```

But getting this error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'parti_a.country' in 'on clause'
```

can any expert one explain where is the exact problem?

Comment: *where is the exact problem?* Output expression is evaluated after GROUP BY, when `parti_a.country` is already invisible.

Comment: @Akina can you please suggest any edit there?

Comment: For further help, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: But I have to join it with the country conditions, then?

Comment: I think the problem is in your sub query, where it doesn't understand the parti_a table

Comment: *can you please suggest any edit there?* Convert correlated subquery to common subquery (or CTE) and use it in FROM section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total points of the participants in `round = 'B759883'` by country, then there is no need for the subquery:

```
SELECT p.country,
       SUM(t.total_pts) country_pts
FROM team_members t INNER JOIN participants p 
ON p.ParticipantID = t.participant 
WHERE round = 'B759883'
GROUP BY p.country
```

For clarity (and because it is a good practice) you should also qualify the column `round` with the alias of the table it belongs.
Also the columns that you use in the `ORDER BY` clause are not allowed because they are not aggregated columns and they are not included in the `GROUP BY` clause.
So maybe you want to sort by

```
ORDER BY country_pts DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a ton  . You really make my day better.